# When I replace a fragment the scroll is not to the top

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-scrollview

I have an frame in an activity which received fragments based on button clicks at the bottom menu of the activity.

The Fragment I I have in question is structured like below. If I click off of the fragment when i'm at the scrolltop to another and then back to this one it stays at the top but if I scroll 1/2 way down the fragment and then leave and come back it is like 10% scrolled from the top. an odd behavior i'm not sure how to rectify.

> Main Activity ->>viewpager1(frameLayout)->fragment1->frag1_constraint(ScrollView)

**Fragment 1 Layout**
[image: Fragment 1 Layout]

**Main Activity Layout**

[image]

Comment: please edit your questions and provide flow with names of the views you use. Now it is not clear which view where suppose to be

Comment: @BorisRuzanov I added the Main Activity structure and fragment to the question